# Error 350 with layout_height (Android Studio)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am getting this error when i try to build my application:

```
error: '350' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_height (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: '350' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_height (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294]., sources=[C:\Users\chris\Documents\GitHub\IFB398\MiBaseApplication\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_login_screen.xml:30], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

I am using Android studio and I am really new to all this.

EDIT 1:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/UsernameEditText"
        android:layout_width="307dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.513"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.55" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/LogoImageView"
        android:layout_width="350"
        android:layout_height="350"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/mibaselogo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/PasswordEditText"
        android:layout_width="309dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.514"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/UsernameEditText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.085" />
```

I have not added all code. Just the section above and below the error. (I am assuming that the error was on line 30 which is the start of the image.

Comment: post your XML code.

Comment: post activity_login_screen.xml

Comment: post your xml code.

Comment: Share your xml code

Comment: You should not be using hard coded values for width and height anyway

Comment: please check your <image view height and width not give properly 350 is wrong please it 350 dp and then run

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify dimension unit like **dp** or **dip**.  For **android:layout_height** attribute use **"350dp"** instead of **"350".**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You must give the valid height

Use match_parent or wrap_content or valid dimensions

```
android:layout_height="350dp" //right one
```

You may be mistakenly give the wrong height

```
android:layout_height="350"  //wrong one
```

Answer (score 1):

Must use specific dimensions like **dip** or **dp**.Update code:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/LogoImageView"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/mibaselogo" />
```

Answer (score 1):

What if I want to specify a percentage? I receive the following message:

> error APT2259: '50%' is incompatible with attribute height (attr)
> dimension.

Answer (score 0):

**Check your xml code**

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_select"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="Select"
            android:background="#d57200"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I think you not give the valid height and width, please check your xml code